# Legacy RMI call from a Spring Application

Tags: spring, rmi, legacy, corba

we have a service running in another server and can be accessed using legacy rmi calls (Corba). This server has nothing to do with Spring and lives in another place and we dont have any influence on the development and source.

We have a Spring Application lives in a weblogic server, and in this application we have some proxy classes, which are accessing the plain RMI and getting the data. Unfortunately, this method has the implication, that we can not use the spring bean injections and we can not mock up the Proxy Classes in our unit tests.

So we are searching a method, accessing the legacy rmi from a Spring (Bean) Context. I searched the web, but came up always with the same result, where the server is also a spring app.

Who can give me a clue, where I should search or is there any framework, library etc. which can help me to solve the problem.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RmiProxyFactoryBean` to access to traditional RMI services, not only Spring RMI Invokers.

For traditional RMI proxies, use the RMI service interface or a interface that mirror the RMI service interface, but don't declare the `RemoteExceptions`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried a "Hello World" and it is functioning well.